# Flutter showDialog() when Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification is received

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've configured Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) as described in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/) and it is working as expected. iOS and Android devices receive a notification, and if the notification is tapped, the application opens.

I would like to show an alert dialog when the notification is tapped and the app opens, since the notification menu on iOS does not show the entire notification body content if it exceeds a certain amount of characters.

I've tried adding to the code provided in the linked docs as follows, but `showDialog` requires a `context`. As these methods are defined in the `main.dart` file, no context is available?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.notification != null) {
      showDialog(
          context: context, // suggests importing dart.js
                            // this.context => "invalid reference to 'this' expression" 
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text(message.notification!.title!),
                content: Text(message.notification!.body!),
              ));
    }
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GlobalKey:

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.notification != null && navigatorKey.currentContext != null) {
      showDialog(
          context: navigatorKey.currentContext,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text(message.notification!.title!),
                content: Text(message.notification!.body!),
              ));
    }
  });
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      // Setting a global key for navigator
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Because you are getting the context of HomePage, why not move the method to initState of HomePage

Comment: You are right. It's better to move `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` logic to `myApp`'s initState.

Comment: In my case has two different GlobalKey and show dialog has been called multiple times.